# PHP-MySQL : Multiple Group By and while

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, while-loop

I am a self-taught using PHP and MySql. I am facing a problem that I can not understand:
I have a database that contains the following fields:
- date
- hours
- email
- product
- quantity
Every time a customer buys a product, I record in the database the information listed above. (one line per product.). If the customer buys several products at the same time, the date, time and email are identical.

My wish:
I would gather in a table on a single line the date, time and email if they are identical and all products purchased for these three pieces of information.

My problem is the following:
I use the query: SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER GROUP BY date, time, email "then I distribute in a table with" while ".

MySQL group records "date", "hour" and "email" correctly, but the display of products is inconsistent.

Here is my code:

```
$query_customer = "SELECT * FROM CLIENT GROUP BY date, hour, email";
mysql_query($query_customer) or die('Error customer table '.$query_customer.' <br/>'.mysql_error());
$result_customer=mysql_query($query_customer);

    $row_customer = '';
    $name_product = '';
    $quantity_product = '';

    while($distribution_customer = mysql_fetch_array($result_customer))
    {
    $email = '<span>'.$distribution_customer['email'].'</span>';
    $date = $distribution_customer['date'].' at '.$distribution_customer['hour'];
    $quantity_product .= '(x'.$distribution_customer['quantity'].')';
    $name_product .= '<span>'.$distribution_customers['product'].'</br> '.$quantite_produit.'</span>';

    $row_customer .= '
            <tr>
                <td>'.$date.'</td>
                <td>'.$email.'</td>
                <td>'.$name_product.'</td>
            </tr>
        ';
    }
        <table>
        <?php echo $row_customer ?>
        </table>
```

I think I am not far from the solution but I can not find the angle of attack. Maybe someone will help me to see more clearly?
Should I use "group_concat"?

Thank you very much for your insights.

Comment: You could use `GROUP_CONCAT()`, but you're probably better to sort the results in MySQL and then as you loop over the resultset in PHP, test for whether the current record belongs to the same order as the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is due to the lack of normalization in your database. e.g. if you have a `table` (not database as you wrote) with the fields `"username", "password", "email", other user-related columns, "product name", "product description", "product price", other product-related columns, "quantity", "date" etc` you will have A LOT of redundant information in your database and you will have headaches when needed to update this data. Please note that this is an exaggerated example.

In order to prevent information of being redundant in the database, you need to design your tables so that they are at least 3NF (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form). Your database will have to contain 4 tables:

```
user (id, username, password, email, ...)
product (id, productName, productDescription, price, ...)
cart (id, user_id, date, totalValue, totalNumberOfItems, delivered, ...)
cart_items (id, cart_id, product_id, quantity, ...)
```

...and selecting something from these table would be like this:

`select * from user, product, cart, cart_items where user.id=cart.user_id and product.id=cart_items.product_id and cart.id=cart_items.cart_id and cart.delivered=0 group by cart.id sort by user.username asc;`

Regards

Comment: Hello and thank you for responding so quickly.
I understand what you advise me and after thinking, I decided to see my code upstream because I want to have the least possible table. So I simply prefer to save all the products on the same line in the same cell. A "explode" PHP will allow me to distribute as I wish.

Thank you very much.

cordially